# 301 redirect by replacing character in URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

Somehow Google has indexed the wrong URL. No idea how, but alas, here we are.

I need to forward all URLs with this setup...

`example.com/features.reports` to `example.com/features/reports`

The constant here is the domain and "features"...basically anything with `features.` should forward to `features/`

How can I set that up in routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
match "/features.*path" => redirect("/features/%{path}")
```

This will return a 301 permanently moved redirect.

See [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info on redirect and globbing.